# access to restricted uri denied on jquery includes - works fine with www subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dns

For some reason the jquery includes on this page throws a 1012 error but only if I view this page from the domain without the www

http://marchofdimes.com/ovulation_calendar.html

The error doesn't show up from the www subdomain.

http://www.marchofdimes.com/ovulation_calendar.html

I could change the script src to include a full path name, I suppose that might solve the problem but wanted to ask why it's happening in the first place. And the recommended fix.

Thanks

Comment: problem also seems specific to firefox and IE. doesn't show up in chrome. guess it's because of security settings?

Comment: Apart from lots of CSS errors I get this one in FF 4b6 for www-less: `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "chrome://yslow/content/yslow-firefox-net.js Line: 444"]` and this for the URL with www: `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0002 (NS_BINDING_ABORTED) [nsIStreamListener.onDataAvailable]"  nsresult: "0x804b0002 (NS_BINDING_ABORTED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://yslow/content/yslow-firefox-net.js :: anonymous :: line 476"  data: no]`

Comment: There are other problems with that page: when a dropdown menu is opened (e.g., 'cycle length'), the information box is hidden beneath it. And it doesn't show me when I should have intercourse.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. Yeah, I'm aware that there's lots of issues with the css/html. But my cries to the relevant parties fall on deaf ears so I'm just working on my piece - making sure the calendar works properly. 

The intercourse icon is for logged in users only! It's more of an intercourse logging tool than anything else... The fertile/ovulation days are presumably the days people should have intercourse if they're trying to conceive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ajax call you make with this line

```
$("#result_message").load('http://www.marchofdimes.com/hs.xsl/oc_Form.xml',..
```

change it to

```
$("#result_message").load('/hs.xsl/oc_Form.xml',...
```

The issue is that an ajax call from the `non-www` to the `www` violates the same origin policy

more info at

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: thanks very much. makes sense... i'll make this change tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
$("#result_message").load('http://www.marchofdimes.com/hs.xsl/oc_Form.xml', { //ajax call to dynament
```

www.marchofdimes.com is a different hostname to marchofdimes.com, so you hit [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Use a relative URI (i.e. one that starts with a `/hs.xsl` and not `http://`.

Alternatively, pick one hostname to be canonical and redirect (with a 301 status) all requests from the other to it.